# hyperlinks reappearing upon PDF creation

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, hyperlink, preview

I am using word v16.49 and Preview to convert to PDF. Even if I remove a hyperlink from the .doc file, the hyperlink is recreated in the final PDF (though it isn't blue).  From poking around, I know this is a feature enabled to increase accessibility, but I have not found where or how to turn this feature off.

Comment: Did you really remove the hyperlink, or did you just remove the underline and the blue text color? If that is the case, it appears to be normal text, but in fact it is still a hyperlink. And then it is still a hyperlink when you convert your document to a pdf